# Deallocating memory using a pointer to an element in an array

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I have the following C++ code:

```
int main(){
    unsigned char *abc = (unsigned char *)calloc(100,1);
    unsigned char *def = &abc[50];
    delete def;
}
```

Would this deallocate all the memory allocated by the call to calloc, or just the memory starting at the memory location where `def` points to?

Comment: What unsigned char *def = &abc[50]; does is that, the def pointer is only making a reference to where the pointer *abc at position abc[50] is pointing to. def should be pointing at the element in that location however it`s empty at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is undefined behavior. A crash, if you are lucky.

According to C++ standard (Working Draft, N3291=11-0061)

> **3.7.4.2 Deallocation functions [basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]**
>
> ...
>
> The value of the
>   first argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation
>   function is one supplied in the standard library, the call has no effect. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined
>   if the value supplied to operator `delete(void*)` in the standard library is not one of the values returned
>   by a previous invocation of either operator `new(std::size_t)` or operator `new(std::size_t, constvstd::nothrow_t&)` in the standard library ...

There are several problems here. First, you should use `free` if you used `calloc`.

Then, you should pass to `free` the same pointer you got from `calloc`.

`calloc` allocates memory as one continuous block, and the entire block gets deallocated with `free`, not a part of it.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/.

Answer (score 3):

`delete` can only delete memory allocated with `new`.

for memory allocated with `calloc` deallocate it using `free`.

and no, you can't just use a pointer to somewhere *inside* the allocated memory.

---

in C++, deal with simple character strings by using `std::string` from the `<string>` header.

it takes care of memory management for you.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't necessarily deallocate anything as it has undefined behavior.  You can only call `delete` on a pointer which was allocated with `new`.  Not only was the memory allocated with `calloc` instead of `new`, but you are also not passing a pointer to what `calloc` returned, but to some other position within that block of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't *abc undefined there?  delete def; wouldn't do anything if there is nothing to delete!